# Android Populating ListView with wanted data from database

Tags: java, android, database, simplecursoradapter

I have an Alarm Application which stores its alarms into a database so it can retrieve it `ON_BOOT`, now I'm thinking of implementing a display of all alarms, depending the day you select. I have been thinking using a `ListView` and populating it with alarms. I have read that `SimpleCursorAdapter` is a way to go but I was wondering how would I populate so it displays only alarms which are set on Monday, for example? It seems I would need to run a query somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Don't know if I get your problem... Just create a query for your database and add "WHERE weekday = 'Monday'" and use this query for the list view's cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an SQL query that will only return alarms on a given date:

```
SELECT * FROM alarms WHERE strftime( '%w', date_column ) = day
```

where "day" is a number corresponding to the day of the week (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc).

If you're storing the date as just a day of the week, then it's easier:

```
SELECT * FROM alarms WHERE day_column = day
```

Comment: yeah okay i just don't know the whole thing how to use it in a cursor and display those results in a listview